# Unitary and central in a C* algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, c-star-algebras

Is it true that if an element of a unital $C^*$-algebra is unitary and commutes with all other elements, then it is a scalar multiple of the identity?

Comment: No.  $C[0,1]$ is commutative.  A function $f\in C[0,1]$ is unitary if $|f(x)|\equiv 1$.  There are many non-scalar functions like that.  For example $\exp(2\pi i x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra, and $Z(A)$ the center of $A$.  Then $Z(A)$ is a $C^*$ sub-algebra of $A$ and a commutative unital $C^*$-algebra by itself.  $Z(A)$ is therefore isomorphic to $C(\Delta)$ where $\Delta$ is the maximal-ideal-space/space-of-homomorphisms of $Z(A)$.  $\Delta$ is a compact Hausdorff space (with the weak-* topology from the Banach-space dual of $Z(A)$.)  The unitaries of $Z(A)$ correspond to functions from $\Delta$ to the unit circle $S^1 = \{z: |z|=1\}\subseteq\Bbb{C}$, and they are unitaries of $A$ as well.  Since $\Delta$ is compact-Hausdorff, it is normal and by Urysohn's lemma completely normal.  It follows that if $\Delta$ has more than $1$ point, there are non-constant continuous functions from $\Delta$ to $\Bbb{R}$ and therefore to $S^1$.  Therefore, the unitaries of $Z(A)$ are all scalar if and only if $\Delta$ is a one-point space if and only if $Z(A) = \Bbb{C}$.

Obviously not every $C^*$-algebra has $Z(A)=\Bbb{C}$, but there are such.  If they also happen to be von-Neumann algebras, they're called factors.  For example $M_n(\Bbb{C})$ and the algebra of bounded operators on an infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space are (type I) factors.  There are also $C^*$-algebras with $Z(A)=\Bbb{C}$ that are not von-Neumann.  These can be constructed for instance from ergodic actions of groups on topological spaces.

Comment: Simple implies trivial centre, but the converse is not true (easiest example: $B(H)$).

Comment: Thanks, I dropped the 'simple'.

Answer (score 2):

This is false in any C$^*$-algebra with non-trivial centre.

The simplest example is to take $u=(1,-1)$ in $\mathbb C^2$.

Comment: von-Neumann algebras that are factors are unital $C^{*}$-algebras with center equal to $\Bbb{C}$.  So it's not 'any' $C^{*}$-algebra.  Maybe 'most'.

Comment: Yes, of course. The element in the question is central by definition. I have corrected that in my answer.